# Contacting ex colleague

Tags: employment

I contacted an ex colleague in a non professional manner, it was unwanted and after a brief exchange of messages no other contact was made.

She later confided in an employee/friend (who still works at the company I am at). This reached managements ears and they brought me in to discuss inappropriate contact.

If this said person is an ex employee from over a year ago and it's outside working hours and employer premises is this an issue they could reprimand me for/have any right to be involved?

Thanks for ready :)

Comment: There is also something to be said for location being a factor here as there may be different harassment laws in different parts of the world.

Comment: Can you tell us more about "in a non-professional manner"? I initially read that as meaning "outside of a work context", but I'm presuming you meant something less appropriate than that.

Comment: For what it's worth, I migrated this here specifically because we didn't see any legal issues stemming from this but possibly only policy and interpersonal issues.

Answer (score 3):

It would be unusual of management to do such a thing unless they felt that what you did made them as a company look bad. They may be worried about the repercussions of you doing the same thing to current employees and then they would be culpable since they knew of your behavior beforehand. I would not be surprised is a lawyer told them to reprimand you.

In the US at least, they likely have the right to fire you for no reason at all and they do have a right to protect their professional reputation. People are reprimanded/fired for inappropriate posting on Facebook, for instance.

Legally your rights are going to vary from jurisdiction to jurisdiction. Check with a lawyer to be sure of your rights if you think you will fight this. It will be costly and time-consuming even if you are in the right.

However, apparently what you did was bad enough that your managers felt it warranted a talking to. I personally would pay attention to what they said and change your behavior and make an effort to make sure they see you behave appropriately with any employees that your sexual orientation might make you want to date. I would not date anyone from this company while you are employed there or anyone who used to work there. Be especially careful at any holiday parties.

You could look for another job since you have ruined your reputation at this one. However before you do that, remember that it is a small world out there in most professions and once you get a reputation for inappropriate behavior, fewer companies are going to be interested. As you have seen, personal behavior can get back to current employers and future employers, so first I would clean up the inappropriate personal behavior.